# Telerik RadGrid Pdf Export not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

This code is being run when a button is clicked on my page:

```
protected void btnExportToPdfButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ProjectListGrid.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
      this.ProjectListGrid.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageLeftMargin = Unit.Parse(".2in");
      this.ProjectListGrid.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageRightMargin = Unit.Parse(".2in");
    ApplyStylesToPdfExport(this.ProjectListGrid.MasterTableView);
    this.ProjectListGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToPdf();
}

public void ApplyStylesToPdfExport(GridTableView tableView)
{  
    // Get access to the header in the grid
    GridItem headerItem = tableView.GetItems(GridItemType.Header)[0];

    // Apply CSS Styles to the header
    headerItem.Style["font-size"] = "8pt";
    headerItem.Style["background-color"] = "#777";
    headerItem.Style["color"] = "white";

    // Apply CSS Styles to each cell in the header
    foreach (TableCell cell in headerItem.Cells)
    {
        cell.Style["color"] = "red";
    }
}
```

The pdf exports, just with no custom styles applied at all.
I have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the control seems to rebind itself and thus it wipes out your inline styles. Possible cause for this behavior is that you set ExportSettings.IgnorePaging to **true** in your markup. If this is not the case, and if you still have this problem, post your code here so that I can examine it.